# optimal css selector in transition on background when resized

Tags: css, background, resize, css-transitions

```js
$(function(){
  $('div').click(function(){
   $('h3').toggleClass('collapsed');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background: url('http://deiaactivity.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bgimage2.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  padding: 2em;
}
h3 {
  padding: 12em 1em;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
h3.collapsed {
  padding: 6em 1em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>Click me!</h3>
</div>
```

Is there any way to a transition effect on the background image resize?

-EDIT-

I added now, to test

```
* {
   transition: 1s linear all;
}
```

And it's possible, but I can't use this fatal (haha) selector in this project, so what would be the right one (the ones that select less childrens of the background image container, but transitions the background when it resizes)?

```js
$(function(){
  $('div').click(function(){
   $('h3').toggleClass('collapsed');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
    transition: 1s linear all;
}
div {
  background: url('http://deiaactivity.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bgimage2.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  padding: 2em;
}
h3 {
  padding: 12em 1em;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
h3.collapsed {
  padding: 6em 1em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>Click me!</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `background-size`? You might also want to test `background-position`, `background-clip`, `background-attachment` and `background-blend-mode` though all of them are quite unlikely to support transitions or actually be the one you're after. I hope you don't mind I didn't take the time to test myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit CSS rule like this:

```
h3 {
  padding: 12em 1em;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}
```

Here is [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/itoriginal/Lca96bp7/)

Comment: Nice! you nailded for this example, unfortunatelly; in my real scenario there are many different of content changes; but I might be able to select them all efficiently. You helped, thanks! (I am just waiting a little for  other answers?)

Comment: May be this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/itoriginal/Lca96bp7/1/) will fit for your scenario better I add height which will collapse or expand by click

Comment: Sorry if didn't explain myself, but the transition wants to be on the image, specially